# How to live broadcast with over 1000 users

Tags: webrtc, broadcast, live

I am developing a project of livestream with larger wiewer, i used WebRTC and it succeed but one problem here that the viewer is limited under 200.
Could you tell me the technique do that my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Who says 200 users? It's scalable to your machine CPU.

The orange curve below is the number of concurrent webpages of [Venice beach stream](http://umediaserver.net/umediaserver/demohtml5WebRTCplayer.html), **notice 1000 players:**

[image]

The test was conducted with Unreal Media Server v13.0 on AWS EC2 m4.2xlarge instance:
Intel Xeon **8 cores** CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30 GHz, 32 Gb RAM, Windows Server 2016.

So if you had **16 cores** instead of 8, you could have about twice as more players.

You can see from this graph that WebRTC players are about 10 times more CPU expensive than RTMP players, but it's still scalable with most of WebRTC SFUs, such as Ant media server, Unreal Media Server, Janus and many others.

Comment: Where are the bottlenecks/costs for WebRTC? Did you use hardware acceleration for SRTP? Are you writing UDP messages in batch? I just worry this is about a certain WebRTC implementation, and not the protocols themselves.

Comment: We are using Google's native WebRTC API, just like 99% of SFUs out there, so the performance shown above is inherent to Google's native WebRTC API. There is no additional overhead on top of it - we are just passing encoded frames to native WebRTC API and it does the rest. I know you have an original WebRTC implementation in Go, so post your performance graphs here, based on the ingested input from the same RTSP camera (we can provide RTSP URL). We would be very curious to see your performance.

Comment: Yea I would love to do that! What tool do you use to generate the graphs? What do you use as a WebRTC client? I don't have any of this tooling, but would love to learn it. I will start a repo under the Pion project that wires it all up -- I also don't mean this to be a competition, I genuinely just want WebRTC to reach it's full potential! thanks

Comment: Competition is actually great! Part of huge overhead of Google's native WebRTC API is a ton of unnecessary and not optimized code; and of course there is no use of hardware acceleration for SRTP. We did only minor optimizations, will wait until WebRTC 1.0 is out as a standard - then we plan to re-write it from scratch. So let's see how your Go implementation handles the load! Our test client was that same WebRTC player of Venice beach stream - we used a webpage hosting 20 such players and used a few dozens of AWS instances, running that webpage, to reach 1000 players.

Comment: I love your enthusiasm, I am used to people being less supportive :) Pion is just a fun Open Source project. I am really impressed with how much unreal can do, if you are ever bored send me a email sean @ siobud.com would love to talk about WebRTC/video stuff more!

Comment: I moved this to https://github.com/pion/rtsp-bench, but the end result is I can hit 14k PeerConnections and never go above 40% CPU usage! This repo includes all the tooling to reproduce this easily as well.